# another column of date and convert it to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame of hourly data for BTC. The index Column is datetime which includes the date and time for hourly bar. I want to add another column matching the same dates as the original data frame.
It means there will be 12 bars with same date.

then I want to change the index to this new date column (this new column has the same date but has not time)

please guide in easy code. thank you

I am almost lost. I tried something like "datetime.datetime.date()" but nothing is working
also I read many topics on "stacoverflow" but none of them is matching my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```python
df = df.set_index(df.index.to_series().dt.date)
```

Sample input:

```
                     data
2023-04-13 08:00:00    10
2023-04-13 09:00:00    20
2023-04-13 10:00:00    30
2023-04-13 11:00:00    40
2023-04-13 12:00:00    50
2023-04-13 13:00:00    60
2023-04-13 14:00:00    70
2023-04-13 15:00:00    80
2023-04-13 16:00:00    90
2023-04-13 17:00:00   100
2023-04-13 18:00:00   110
2023-04-13 19:00:00   120
2023-04-14 08:00:00    11
2023-04-14 09:00:00    21
2023-04-14 10:00:00    32
2023-04-14 11:00:00    41
2023-04-14 12:00:00    51
2023-04-14 13:00:00    61
2023-04-14 14:00:00    71
2023-04-14 15:00:00    81
2023-04-14 16:00:00    91
2023-04-14 17:00:00   101
2023-04-14 18:00:00   111
2023-04-14 19:00:00   121
```

Output:

```
            data
2023-04-13    10
2023-04-13    20
2023-04-13    30
2023-04-13    40
2023-04-13    50
2023-04-13    60
2023-04-13    70
2023-04-13    80
2023-04-13    90
2023-04-13   100
2023-04-13   110
2023-04-13   120
2023-04-14    11
2023-04-14    21
2023-04-14    32
2023-04-14    41
2023-04-14    51
2023-04-14    61
2023-04-14    71
2023-04-14    81
2023-04-14    91
2023-04-14   101
2023-04-14   111
2023-04-14   121
```

---

If you want to preserve the original datetime index, you can do something like this:

```python
df = ( df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'orig_index'})
    .set_index(df.index.to_series().dt.date) )
```

Output:

```
                    orig_index  data
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 08:00:00    10
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 09:00:00    20
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 10:00:00    30
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 11:00:00    40
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 12:00:00    50
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 13:00:00    60
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 14:00:00    70
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 15:00:00    80
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 16:00:00    90
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 17:00:00   100
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 18:00:00   110
2023-04-13 2023-04-13 19:00:00   120
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 08:00:00    11
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 09:00:00    21
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 10:00:00    32
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 11:00:00    41
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 12:00:00    51
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 13:00:00    61
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 14:00:00    71
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 15:00:00    81
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 16:00:00    91
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 17:00:00   101
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 18:00:00   111
2023-04-14 2023-04-14 19:00:00   121
```